# What is the preferred word to use to know if the partner is grasping what you are explaining?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Suppose that you are explaining something to someone. Which of these is more appropriate to use?

> ¿Me entiendes?
>
> ¿Me explico?

If you use "**me explico**" it could be interpreted as if you are not good enough to explain the idea.

If you use "**me entiendes**" it could be interpreted as if you are doubting that the person is good enough to grasp the idea.

- So what's the preferred expression?
- Are there any other expressions that I should use?
- Should I just not say anything and keep going with the explanation?

Comment: this thing happens in other languages

Comment: Maybe '¿Tiene sentido?' is best? Your asking if what your saying makes sense, which doesn't favor either side really.

Comment: Another common expression, but maybe restricted to Argentina, since nobody mentioned it, is “¿me seguís?” (literally, “are you following me?”.

Comment: `¿Me dejo entender?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Michael, neither *¿me explico?* or *¿me entiendes?* are bad choices.

I would say that *¿me entiendes?* would be the one I would use.

On the other hand *¿estamos?* may be used based on the country/cultural context you are. I don't think I have ever used nor have I heard too many people use *¿estamos?* to ask if I'm understanding something.

Answer (score 2):

I'm partial to `¿estamos?`:

> Primero A, después B y luego C.  ¿Estamos?  Bien, ahora tenemos que
>   seguir con pasos D y E.

It goes particularly well at "checkpoints".

Having said that, I disagree with your premise: I don't think you're putting either your ability to explain or your interlocutor's ability to understand in doubt by asking `¿me explico?` or `¿me entiendes?`, especially if you're dealing with complicated concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like

> ¿Se entiende?
>
> ¿Está claro?
>
> ¿Queda claro?
>
> ¿Está bien? (meaning: Do you get what I'm saying so far?)

so the other person feels more willing to say something, without feeling like he is being doubted.